# What is the difference between "luma" and "hela"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Both seem related to the light. *Hel* seems to be used for colors while *Lum* seems to be used for everything else. What is the real difference of meaning between them?

Answer (score 4):

*Hela* is not limited to colors - but you seem to have a good grasp on the basic differences. You can have a *luma tago* and a *hela tago*. *Luma* means there's a lot of light. *Hela* means it's "bright" (which means a lot of light) or that it's "light" in the sense of having white mixed in - like light grey.

Check out the definitions in PIV. *Hela* is defined essentially the same as *luma* with a few secondary definitions added on.

luma

1. Daŭre lumanta

hela

1. Donanta aŭ ricevanta fortan vivan lumon
2. Enhavanta multe da blanko (hela ruĝo)
3. Vigle, akute sonora (hele sonantaj trumpetoj)

Comment: Could you post the definitions along with a translation?

Comment: Done, as requested.